\fullcite comand with \newline as \newblockpunct with biblatex
In my *.bbx file I have defined \renewcommand*{\newblockpunct}{\newline} to have authors, title and journal each in separate lines. This works well in the actual bibliography. Now I also want to define a new \myfullcite command that gives me the same result. So far I tried
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\defcounter{minnames}{6}%
      \defcounter{maxnames}{10}%
     }
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

which mostly works as expected. But It doesn't add the line breaks after the authors or the title. From what I understand from the biblatex documentation this is because
\AtUsedriver{%
\delimcontext{bib}%
\let\finentry\blx@finentry@usedrv
\let\newblock\relax
\let\abx@macro@bibindex\@empty
\let\abx@macro@pageref\@empty}

redefines the \newblock command when I use \usedriver. I tried adding \usedriver{\let\newblock\newline}{\thefield{entrytype}}, but this produced excessive new lines and oddly placed commas. What do I have to put in the first argument of \usedriver to have \newblock behave correctly? Ideally I don't want to use \AtUseDriver* because I use the \fullcite command elsewhere.

You can use the starred version of \AtUsedriver to clear the hook. Then you can copy the original invocation of \AtUsedriver, but drop the \let\newblock\relax that disables the blocking mechanism.
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newblockpunct}{\newline}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\defcounter{minnames}{6}%
      \defcounter{maxnames}{10}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
\AtUsedriver*{%
  \delimcontext{bib}%
  \let\finentry\blx@finentry@usedrv
  \let\abx@macro@bibindex\@empty
  \let\abx@macro@pageref\@empty}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \myfullcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


